# Goddess Ushas : references in the Vedas

Tags: rig-veda, reference-request

Ushas (Marici for Buddhists) is the goddess of the dawn. What are the passages in the vedas where she is mentioned exactly?

[image]

Comment: Wiki says "Ushas is mentioned in numerous hymns of the Rigveda.[12] Forty of its hymns are dedicated to her, while her name appears in other additional hymns.[13] "...do u want something like this?

Comment: Please with the RV reference , if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many epithets ( Indra, Vishnu, etc) referring to various aspects of the Almighty God, Ushas (Dawn) is an epithet used in Rig Veda to indicate emerging of REALISATION/WISDOM.

Many hymns were dedicated to Ushas in Rig Veda. [Forty of its hymns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushas) are dedicated to her, while her name appears in other additional hymns.

---

For example:

[Mandala 1:](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rvi01.htm)

XLVIII, XLIX

[Mandala III](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rvi03.htm)

XLI

[Mandala IV](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rvi04.htm)

LI, LII

[Mandala V](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rvi05.htm)

LXXIX, LXXX

and so on.

Comment: Thank You. Also of the almighty Goddess.

Comment: The list in Wikipedia is incomplete. I was searching a list with all the referrals, but is ok, i will search by myself.

Comment: @LuckyPashu: I could not understand your comment -  Also of the almighty Goddess

Comment: no worries. I was searching the precise list of references in the rig veda. Forty hymns are not listed in Wikipedia, this is why i commented , just few of them.